# jQuery Endless Loop to update status

Tags: jquery, loops, while-loop

I have a function and will call it everytime a checkbox div is selected from a drop down list. Below is my function:

```
function arming(){
            $('#armText').change(function(){
                if ($('#armCB_1').is(':checked')){
                    $.post('/request', {key_pressed:"arming_status"}).done(function(reply){
                        $('#armStatus').empty().append("<h3>The Arming Status is " + reply).show();
                    });
                }
                else{
                    $('#armStatus').hide();
                }
            });
        }
```

My question is, how can i update the "armStatus" for a certain period of time and only stop updating when the checkbox is unchecked? Also, i want the rest of the program to continue running. Is it possible to use a while(1) as endless loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the current solution to my program is:

```
function arming() {
var loop = setInterval(function () {
    $.post('/request', {
            key_pressed: "arming_status"
        }).done(function (reply) {
            $('#armStatus').empty().append("<h3>The Arming Status is " + reply).show();
        });
}, 200)
$('#armText').change(function () {
    if (!$('#armCB_1').is(':checked')) {            //if it is unchecked
        clearInterval(loop);
    } 
});
```

}

But it doesn't do it again if i check and uncheck the checkbox...

**UPDATE - better solution:**

```
function arming() {
            var $arm = $('#armStatus'),
                $checkbox = $('#armCB_1');

            $checkbox.change(function() {
               $arm.toggle(this.checked);
            })

            setInterval(function(){
              if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) { 
                 $.post('/request', {key_pressed: "arming_status"}).done(function (reply) {
                    $('#armStatus').empty().append("<h3>The Arming Status is " + reply).show();
                 });
              }
              else {
                  $arm.hide();
              }
            }, 2000);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function that loops it self till conditions are met:

```
function loopFunction() {
    var $ = jQuery,
    if (!$('#armCB_1').is(':checked')){
        //do something
        setTimeout(function() {
            loopFunction();
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var $arm = $('#armStatus'),
    $checkbox = $('#armCB_1');

$checkbox.change(function() {
   $arm.toggle(this.checked);
})

setInterval(function(){
  if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) { // if ($arm.is(':visible')) { 
     $.post('/request', {key_pressed:"arming_status"}).done(function(reply){
           $arn.html("<h3>The Arming Status is " + reply).show();
     });
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: thanks again for the solution. :) How would i clear the interval in this case?

Comment: @yvonnezoe There is no need to clear the interval, I have used an `if` statement instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. setInterval and setTimeout. 
With setInterval you can use clearInterval to end the loop.

e.g.

```
setInterval(function(){}, 200)
```

The code in function would run after every 200ms. The code like following would meet your requirements

```
function arming() {
    var loop = setInterval(function () {
        $.post('/request', {
                key_pressed: "arming_status"
            }).done(function (reply) {
                $('#armStatus').empty().append("<h3>The Arming Status is " + reply).show();
            });
    }, 200)
    $('#armText').change(function () {
        if ($('#armCB_1').is(':checked')) {            
            clearInterval(loop);
        } else {
            $('#armStatus').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you! but why clearInterval when the checkbox is checked? should it be under else?

Comment: It should be whenever you want to loop to finish. I might have placed it at the wrong place

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.setTimeout(action, n). An even better solution can be found here [link]aktuell.de.selfhtml.org/artikel/javascript/timer/#timer (text german, just look at the source). You would 'just' have to disable/enable this Timer on your own